# "Error [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\OnetoMany" in property" on Gitlab CI but not in local env or production

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, gitlab, doctrine

I've written some tests on an symfony 4.4 application and I would like to run these tests on my gitlab CI but I get this error :

> Error [Semantical Error] The annotation
> "@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\OnetoMany" in property
> App\Entity\Client::$logsRegions was never imported     . Did you
> maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?

but I haven't this error neither in my local env nor in production env and I import `Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM` in my entity

Here my Client entity

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use App\Entity\Region\AccessLogRegion;
use App\Entity\Traits\ClientTrait;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
/**
 * Client
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="client")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ClientRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Client
{
    use ClientTrait;
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

   //...

    /**
     * @ORM\OnetoMany(targetEntity=AccessLogRegion::class, mappedBy="client")
     */
    private $logsRegions;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->logsRegions = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getLogsRegions()
    {
        return $this->logsRegions;
    }
}
```

My .gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: jakzal/phpqa:php7.4

before_script:
  - composer install

cache:
  paths:
    - vendor/

stages:
  - UnitTests

phpunit:
  image: php:7.4-apache
  stage: UnitTests
  services:
    - name: mysql:5.7
      alias: mysql
  variables:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: project
    MYSQL_DATABASE: project_test
    MYSQL_USER: root
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: project
    DATABASE_URL: 'mysql://root:project@mysql:3306/project_test'
  before_script:
    - apt-get update && apt-get install -y git libzip-dev
    - curl -sSk https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --disable-tls && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
    - docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql zip
    - php bin/console doctrine:database:drop --force --env=test
    - php bin/console doctrine:database:create --env=test
    - php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --env=test --force
  script:
    - php bin/phpunit
  allow_failure: false
```

Complete gitlab error log :

> $ php bin/console doctrine:database:drop --force --env=test Dropped
> database /tmp/test/test_db.sqlite for connection named default
>
> $ php bin/console doctrine:database:create --env=test
> Created database
> /tmp/test/test_db.sqlite for connection named default
> $ php
> bin/console doctrine:schema:update --env=test --force
>
> In AnnotationException.php line 39:
> [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\OnetoMany" in
> prop     erty App\Entity\Client::$logsRegions was never imported     .
> Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?
>
> doctrine:schema:update [--em EM] [--complete] [--dump-sql]
> [-f|--force] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose]
> [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env
> ENV] [--no-debug] [--]
>
> Cleaning up file based variables
>
> ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

I don't understand why it doesn't work, any help is welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the problem is your annotation `OnetoMany` is invalid because of the case, the proper spelling should be `OneToMany`.

Try replacing it with :

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=AccessLogRegion::class, mappedBy="client")
 */
private $logsRegions;
```